# Import of pyodbc fails

Tags: azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I installed Pyodbc and the SQL driver on MacOS:

`brew list msodbcsql18`

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.0.1.1/.brew_home/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.0.1.1/.brew_home/.bazelrc
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.0.1.1/include/msodbcsql18/msodbcsql.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.0.1.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.0.1.1/odbcinst.ini
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.0.1.1/share/doc/ (2 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql18/18.0.1.1/share/msodbcsql18/resources/en_US/msodbcsqlr18.rll
```

`brew list unixodbc`

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/.bottle/etc/ (2 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/bin/dltest
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/bin/isql
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/bin/iusql
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/bin/odbc_config
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/bin/odbcinst
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/bin/slencheck
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/include/ (11 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/lib/libodbccr.2.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/lib/libodbcinst.2.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/lib/pkgconfig/ (3 files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/lib/ (6 other files)
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9_1/share/man/ (8 files)
```

`pip show  pyodbc`

```
Name: pyodbc
Version: 4.0.32
Summary: DB API Module for ODBC
Home-page: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: MIT
Location: /Users/deniz/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

```
❯ python3                                                            
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/deniz/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/deniz/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libodbc.2.dylib' (no such file)
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

`unixodbc` is missing from your machine.

Use the below command to install it and it should work fine.

`brew install unixodbc`

Comment: it was there, but the symlinks not. I had to set the symlinks then I was able to import

Comment: But I ran into another issue. Created a new post here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987243/pyodbc-issue-odbc-driver-not-found-on-macos)